# Google Drive API Error Description: Code '403' Message: 'The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-drive-api

In Unity I'm trying to receive my drive list id's.
I'm getting the following error:

> UnityGoogleDrive: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> Google Drive API Error Description: Code '403' Message: 'The request is missing a valid API key.'
>
> - Domain: 'global' Reason: 'forbidden' Message: 'The request is missing a valid API key.' LocationType: '' Location: ''

I do have API Key, not sure where I should insert it, (I parsed the generic credentials JSON OAuth file)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;
using UnityGoogleDrive;
using UnityGoogleDrive.Data;

public class GoogleDriveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [ContextMenu("Copy Template In Drive")]
    public void CopyTemplateFromGoogle()
    {
        GoogleDriveFiles.List().Send().OnDone+= GetAllFiles;
    }

    public void GetAllFiles(FileList fileList)
    {
        foreach (var file in fileList.Files)
        {
            Debug.Log(file.Id);
        }
    }

  

}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes I did , i tried to look for a way maybe to insert or request the API Key. but found nothing of sort.

Comment: Which documentation did you read?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files
 this one

Comment: Aren't you using a package/plugin for this? They should have a readme where they explain how their Unity package/plugin works. UnityGoogleDrive?

Comment: your right, it is a package form here: 
https://github.com/Elringus/UnityGoogleDrive
and That's the documentation that they posted

Comment: Did you follow the headline "Setup" in the link you posted? I have never used it, but you did not mention anything about actually doing that...

Comment: yes of course I did the setup. i did mention that I already imported the JSON file into the plugin. i did not have any problem with the setup of the plugin, i fixed my answer, ill posted it

Answer (score 0):

looks like I fixed it
I changed my approach and tried to download current template sheet first - then it gave me new error :

> Google Drive API Error Description: Code '403' Message: 'Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.'

So I used the  Export to mimeType the file.

string fileId = "FILE_ID";

```
    string mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    var request = GoogleDriveFiles.Export(fileId, mimeType);
```

and after I managed to get the field, I could Copy it.

`GoogleDriveFiles.Copy(file);`

Answer (score 0):

Ther is plugin for Unity that you can use [Unity Google Drive Plugin](https://github.com/Elringus/UnityGoogleDrive), you can setup your api key there, and then use Google APIs Client Library for .NET for your program (they support Files Google Drive API).

Plugin supports all the major platforms: Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android and WebGL.

also you can find more info on [Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-drive-sdk-for-unity-free-open-sourced.515360/)

I used it for my project some time ago, works fine.